# Listados de archivos en ubuntu linux

Tags: linux

Tengo que hacer un listado que solo me muestre aquellos archivos que tengan sólo 4 caracteres

Lo he intentado con unos cuantos `ls -a`, probando ciertas cosas pero aún así no lo consigo

¿Cómo se tendría que escribir?

Comment: lo he intentado solo es que no encuentro la información para poder hacer eso, nos pide el listado de 4 caracteres sin incluir la extensión, y pondría ejemplos de mis intentos, pero es que han sido puramente intentos sin saber y probando, ya que nuestro profesor no nos ha dado ni apuntes ni ayuda para este

Comment: He posteado una respuesta, a ver si te sirve, pero el profesor, sino te explica bien las cosas, debe al menos darte las herramientas para que lo sepas buscar (si escribes `man ls` en un terminal linux debería aparecer información ampliada sobre el comando, aunque lo de los comodines no está allí, pero es genérico de linux)

Answer (score 2):

### Respuesta ampliada

Dado que tu `ls` no responde bien a la respuesta original, seguramente debido a algún **alias** para dicho comando predefinido en el archivo `~/.profile` o `~/.bashrc`, propongo esta otra solución para intentar evitar el problema:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 | ls -d -p ???? | grep -v /
```

donde:

- `find ./ -maxdepth 1` nos va a realizar una búsqueda de todos los archivos partiendo de la carpeta desde donde se ejecuta el comando (**`./`**), y sólo en ese nivel (`-maxdepth 1`)
- `ls -d -p ????` nos va a listar dichos archivos, pero listando nombres de directorios como otros ficheros (`-d`) sin listar sus contenidos, y agregándoles una barra final `/ a dichos directorios (-p)
- `????`: el `?` es un [comodín](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) que simula cualquier caracter sólo una vez, por lo tanto lo usamos 4 veces
- `grep -v /` va a deshacerse de los directorios, evitando mostrar cualquier coincidencia con el caracter de barra (`-v /`)

### Respuesta original

Esto puede servirte:

```
ls -d ????
```

donde:

- `-d`: Lista nombres de directorios como otros ficheros, en vez de listar sus contenidos (tal como dicen en su [manual](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/ls/es/))
- `????`: el `?` es un [comodín](https://tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x11655.htm) que simula cualquier caracter sólo una vez, por lo tanto lo usamos 4 veces

Comment: Esto me resuelve gran parte del problema, ahora el listado que me hace con los "????" es de todos los archivos, pero aquellos con 4 caracteres me aparecen subrayados, debería de ser así?

Comment: No, no deberia ser así... quizás tienes algun tipo de filtro en el perfil de tu usuario que sustituye `ls` por otra cosa que hace que aparezca esto.  Revisa tu archivo `.profile` o `.bash_profile` a ver si ves algun alias

Comment: o el archivo `.bashrc` (busca algo como esto, por ejemplo: `alias ls='ls --color=auto'` que sustituye el comando `ls` por ese otro con los parámetros siempre puestos)

Answer (score 1):

Supongamos que tu folder tiene este contenido:

```bash
$ \ls -1
abc
abc1
abc2
abc3
abcd1
abcd2
```

Puedes intentar con `grep`:

```bash
$ \ls -1 | grep -E '^.{4}$'
abc1
abc2
abc3
```

La diagonal invertida en el `\ls` es para ignorar todo alias de ese comando.

O con `find`:

```bash
$ find . -regextype posix-egrep -regex "\.\/.{4}$"
./abc1
./abc2
./abc3
```